# Sharing an OpenGL framebuffer between processes in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, opengl

Is there any way in Mac OS X to share an OpenGL framebuffer between processes? That is, I want to render to an off-screen target in one process and display it in another.

You can do this with DirectX (actually DXGI) in Windows by creating a surface (the DXGI equivalent of an OpenGL framebuffer) in shared mode, getting an opaque handle for that surface, passing that to another process via whatever means you like, then creating a surface in that other process, but passing in the existing handle. You use the surface as a render target in one process then and use it as a texture in the other to consume as you wish. And in fact the whole compositing Window system works like this from Vista onwards.

If this isn't possible I can of course get the contents of the framebuffer into system memory and use cross-process shared memory to get it to the target process, then upload it again from there, but that would be unnecessarily slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're really trying to do this sample code project may be what you want:
[MultiGPUIOSurface sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/MultiGPUIOSurface/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: That looks like just the ticket. I wasn't aware of the IOSurface API but it seems like it was designed for exactly what I want (sharing images in GPU memory between processes). Btw, because it took more than a minute to find, the API docs are here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/IOSurfaceAPI_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011198

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon the context of how you're using it.

> Objects that may be shared between contexts include buffer objects,
>   program and shader objects, renderbuffer objects, sampler objects,
>   sync objects, and texture objects (except for the texture objects
>   named zero).
>
> Some of these objects may contain views (alternate interpretations) of
>   part or all of the data store of another object. Examples are texture
>   buffer objects, which contain a view of a buffer object’s data store,
>   and texture views, which contain a view of another texture object’s
>   data store. Views act as references on the object whose data store is
>   viewed.
>
> Objects which contain references to other objects include framebuffer,
>   program pipeline, query, transform feedback, and vertex array objects.
>   Such objects are called container objects and are not shared.

[Chapter 5 / OpenGL-4.4 core specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf)

The reason you can do those things on Windows and not OS X is that graphics obviously utilizes an API that allows DirectX contexts to be shared between those processes. If OS X doesn't have the capability within the OpenGL API then you're going to have to come up with your own solution. Take a look at [OpenGL Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/opengl-macprogguide/opengl_threading/opengl_threading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH409-SW6), there's a small section that describes using multiple OpenGL contexts.

[image]

Comment: Yeh, I saw the docs about sharing objects between contexts on different threads in the same process. I was just hoping there was some poorly documented way to do that across processes. AFAIK, OS X's window compositing system works the same way as Windows does so there was some faint hope it might, at some level below OpenGL, expose at least a way to do GPU device memory to memory copies without having to bring images back to system memory.